# Can I use Min-1 to find the next to lowest value?

Tags: mysql, max, min

I have a table where I have

Field1 | Field2 | Field3 | Low | High

I don't care about the Field3 breakdown so want to end up with one record for each Field 1 | Field 2 set with:

Field1 | Field2 | Low| High

(since I don't care about the Field 3 breakout)

and end up with e.g

- Apple   | White | 1   | 100
- Banana  | White | 101 | 400
- Kiwi    | white | 402 | 750
- Banana  | Black | 1   | 85
- Apple   | Black | 90  | 205
- Kiwi    | Black | 210 | 5504
  etc

So I figured I could do

```
Create table LOW_HIGH_ALL as (select ID, FIeld1, FIeld2, max(High), min(Low) from LOW_HIGH group by Field1, Field2
```

As you can see each Field 1 represents a range in the Field B field that does not overlap the other.

The problem is there is some 'bad data' so sometimes I end up with:

- Apple   | White | 1   | 100
- Banana  | White | 1   | 400
- Kiwi    | white | 1   | 750

i.e. bad Min data. I can't just assume 1 is always bad. So I thought if I could get next to lowest Min I could get

- Apple | White | 1 | 4   | 100
- Banana| White | 1 | 101 | 400
- Kiwi  | White | 1 | 401 | 700

And can use the difference between 'Min-1' and Min to figure out when I have bad min data (and can use the second value instead, so far it seems to just be one bad min data occasionally.

I have tried to do Min-1 that doesn't work so wondering if there is some other way to extract the second lowest value.

Comment: second highest? second lowest?

Comment: second lowest, my bad, corrected, thanks for the sharp eye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second lowest is a bit of a pain.  But, you can do it in MySQL with the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
Create table LOW_HIGH_ALL as 
    select ID, FIeld1, FIeld2, max(High), min(Low),
           substring_index(substring_index(group_concat(distinct low order by low asc), ',', 2), ',', -1) as min_2
    from LOW_HIGH
    group by Field1, Field2;
```

This concatenates the "low" values together and then extracts the second from the resulting string.

Comment: Thank you. Trying now, running without errors which is always a good sign, multi-million record table so will report back with hopefully good news.

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly. On first run I ended up with SecondLow as the same as Low in many records, upon review there were a # of records with Field1 | Field2 | 1 | 1 so I just changed group by to FIeld1, Field2, Low, High and it worked like a charm. Thanks, great insight into mysql power.

Comment: @MarkH . . . An alternative is to add the `distinct` keyword in the `group_concat()`:  `group_concat(distinct low order by low asc)`.

Comment: I am going to try that, upon review my group by just ended up giving me exactly what I started with, i.e. each Range of Field 1 | Field 2 | Low | High based on Field 3 (where I was trying to get one record with entire range and second value).